Change the default Google Maps background for tiles that are not loaded yet?
At the moment, I am creating an app with Jetpack Compose that uses the Google Maps SDK (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose).  When you move the map fast and the tiles are not loaded yet, you see the default background of the component. For the normal map, this is always beige and for satellite view, this is always a dark blue color.
I would like to customize these background colors to match the light and dark modes of my app better, but I have not found any way to do this using a parameter in the SDK or the JSON-based map style editor (https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), where I also created the dark mode style of my map. I would like to stay with the JSON-based editor, as in my understanding, the cloud-based styling is not free. With the cloud-based editor, it seems to be possible: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-customization/app-background-leg
Thank you in advance for your help!

Could you please raise an issue in Google Public Issue Tracker?

@rafon Hi, I created an issue for it. Feel free to upvote it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/380474993
